# Vuejs - How to call a method on load event on element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

I want to call on load event on element when it being loaded in for loop using vuejs. I have found onload event on page load, but I can't find anyway to do that with element. Here is my code, but it's not working.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(option,opt_index) in question.options" v-on:load="test">
  Testing
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my component.

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';

Vue.use(datePicker);
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
    name: "modal",
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
        test(){
            alert('load');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using v-on:load or @load will work for images. It may not work for `li` like in this example, but can be useful for other things.

Answer (score 11):

That's because a list item (`li`) does not emit a native `load` event.
The next best thing you can do is wait for Vue's next rendering cycle to finish and then call your method. That way you're guaranteed that the whole loop has finished rendering.

In order to wait for the rendering cycle to finish, we need to use Vue's [`nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) utility method:

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';

Vue.use(datePicker);
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
    name: "modal",
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.test();
      });
    },
    methods: {
        test(){
            alert('load');
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we use `nextTick`'s callback version. There's also a promise-based version:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick().then(this.test);
}
```

Or if you're familiar with `async/await`:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.$nextTick();
  this.test();
}
```

Note that this does not fire the `test` method for each `question.options` item.
If you wish to do that, I guess your only option is to still use `nextTick` and then inside `test` loop through `question.options` once more and call a method for each option.